# docker login <dtr-server> gives error 404 not found

Tags: docker, docker-registry

when I try to login on docker private registry it gives the following error:

```
$docker login https://dtr-ip:443

Error response from daemon: Login: <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
(Code: 404; Headers: map[Date:[Wed, 22 Jun 2016 13:51:33 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html] Content-Length:[168] X-Replica-Id:[fa6e7b73277d] Server:[nginx/1.8.0]])
```

My docker trusted registry and UCP are on same node.

docker logs in client side:

```
time="2016-06-22T19:25:08.338336106+05:30" level=info msg="Error logging in to v2 endpoint, trying next endpoint: login attempt to https://54.179.144.153:443/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found" 
time="2016-06-22T19:25:08.621784740+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.23/auth returned error: Login: <html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n (Code: 404; Headers: map[Content-Type:[text/html] Content-Length:[168] X-Replica-Id:[fa6e7b73277d] Server:[nginx/1.8.0] Date:[Wed, 22 Jun 2016 13:55:08 GMT]])"
```

$docker info

```
Containers: 29
Running: 16
Paused: 0
Stopped: 13
Images: 19
Server Version: 1.11.2-cs3
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Name: docker-202:1-201339217-pool
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
Backing Filesystem: xfs
Data file: /dev/loop0
Metadata file: /dev/loop1
Data Space Used: 1.725 GB
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
Data Space Available: 49.69 GB
Metadata Space Used: 3.461 MB
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
Metadata Space Available: 2.144 GB
Udev Sync Supported: true
Deferred Removal Enabled: false
Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-12-01)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
Network: bridge null host overlay
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.26 GiB
Name: automation
ID: Z4XA:KGME:WMYE:RSP4:ILH7:CPFC:PTIN:QUJT:66UT:PC7R:H65R:BIDX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 82
Goroutines: 159
System Time: 2016-06-22T13:59:28.058948802Z
EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Cluster store: etcd://<server-ip>:2050
Cluster advertise: <server-ip>:12376
```

And version of docker are:

```
$docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2-cs3
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   c81a77d
 Built:        Wed Jun  8 01:23:22 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2-cs3
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   c81a77d
 Built:        Wed Jun  8 01:23:22 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I think that when I login to https://dtr-ip:443 it searches for https://dtr-ip:443/v2/. And this url does not have any data.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same generic error; my infrastructure was working fine for 30 days about, but after that I received the below error:

```
Error response from daemon: Login: <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
(Code: 404; Headers: map[Date:[Wed, 22 Jun 2016 13:51:33 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html] Content-Length:[168] X-Replica-Id:[fa6e7b73277d] Server:[nginx/1.8.0]])
```

I took from the event on DTR web-console that the license was expired; after new license installation I haven't seen the error message.